# Html <select> selected attribute doesn't work correctly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, select

I am trying to list some amChart charts in a selection. It doesn't have any default chart so I tried to set the default value for the `<select>` by using selected attribute for one of the options, it is selected on the selection box but doesn't appear on the page.

```js
    var currentChart;
    function showChart( divid ) {
    
      if (currentChart !== undefined)
        currentChart.style.display = "none";
      if ( divid ) {
        currentChart = document.getElementById(divid);
        currentChart.style.display = "block";
      }
      else {
        currentChart = undefined;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <select onchange="showChart(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
      <option value="">Select the chart to show</option>
      <option value="chart1" selected>Chart #1</option>
      <option value="chart2">Chart #2</option>
      <option value="chart3">Chart #3</option>
    </select>
    
    <div id="chart1" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">Chart 1</div>
    <div id="chart2" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">Chart 2</div>
    <div id="chart3" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">Chart 3</div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `jquery`? You are using vanilla `javascript`

Comment: snippet in the question is working fine. what is the problem?

Comment: He wants to show `Chart X` depending on the selected option on load and not only `onchange`

Comment: yes I wanted to chat1 to be selected on load yet its only selected in the lost but now shown.

Comment: Just add `window.onload = function() { ShowChart(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); };` to your code to execute the function as the document is loaded

Comment: @DarkBee can you please add it as an answer so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use onload event only for the tags

```
 <body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>,
 <script>, <style>
```

for other elements you can do in two ways

1. insert the script tag enclosing function to be performed on onload of the element after the element  or
2. by using jquery

> $(document).ready(function() {   showChart('chart1'); });

```html
<script>
  var currentChart;

  function showChart(divid) {
    if (currentChart !== undefined)
      currentChart.style.display = "none";
    if (divid) {
      currentChart = document.getElementById(divid);
      currentChart.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      currentChart = undefined;
    }
  }
</script>
<select onchange="showChart(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
      <option value="">Select the chart to show</option>
      <option value="chart1" selected>Chart #1</option>
      <option value="chart2">Chart #2</option>
      <option value="chart3">Chart #3</option>
    </select>

<div id="chart1" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">char1</div>
<div id="chart2" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">char2</div>
<div id="chart3" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">char3</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  showChart('chart1');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly calling the option you want on window load.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   showChart("chart2");
});

$("#comboBoxID").change(function(e){
   showChart($(this).val());
});

var currentChart;

function showChart(divId){    
  if (currentChart !== undefined)
    currentChart.hide();
  if (divId) {
    currentChart = $("#"+divId);
    currentChart.show();
  }
  else {
    currentChart = undefined;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="comboBoxID">
   <option value="none">None</option>
   <option value="chart1">Chart 1</option>
   <option value="chart2" selected>Chart 2</option>
   <option value="chart3">Chart 3</option>
</select>

<div id="chart1" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">Chart 1</div>
<div id="chart2" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">Chart 2</div>
<div id="chart3" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;">Chart 3</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not select any chart on load as well

Comment: @DarkBee Hence the JavaScript comment!

Comment: ... Why would u produce duplicate code?  Just go with something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/byxoLmca/2/)

Comment: Well, your code duplication is going to go where your javascript comment is, as `$('selector').val()` does not trigger the `onchange` event

Comment: You are right! I suppose you can set option to be selected in HTML markup and just call the showChart in ready with that value.